# HelpDesk system does not support OAuth. What should I do?

Tags: php, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, smtp, imap

In our IT helpdesk system, only simple mail configuration is possible: server, port, username, password, etc. It is used to read emails from a mailbox and create **tickets.**

Since Microsoft doesn't support simple authentication anymore (**only OAuth**), how can I possibly set up mailbox reading?

I know how to send and read emails using Microsoft OAuth, that is not the issue.

My idea is to create a **ghost IMAP app** that fetches messages from Microsoft and passes them to the helpdesk system (man in the middle).

```
IT HELPS DESK --> IMAP --> My Application --> OAuth --> Microsoft
```

To achieve this I have to understand and study the whole **IMAP protocol!!**

Is there a better idea? Does such a library already exist?

I don't know where to start. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: _"Since Microsoft doesn't support simple authentication anymore"_ This doesn't sound correct to me, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/pop3-and-imap4/configure-imap4?view=exchserver-2019) show POP and IMAP options for the latest version of Exchange. Or is this for Exchange Online?

Comment: Ah yeah ok, I see now -- this applies to 365. Maybe [this](https://github.com/simonrob/email-oauth2-proxy) Python proxy or the [Email Engine](https://emailengine.app/) service which has a REST proxy that might be useful.

Comment: Could you actually set up an SMTP server and have 365 forward the help desk account to that?  Take out the whole IMAP middleman.

Comment: @Max Brilliant solution. I have no idea why I didn't think of that!!

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks for the tip, I needed a PHP solution, but this is a good start. Much appreciated.